# Hydration error in nextjs only in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm stuck on this hours.
I deploy my Next-JS application on vercel, and I get there lots of hydration errors.
as I said, in my development mode on my local machine I do not get any errors at all.

I read that the error might occur because of different time zones of the server and client or local machine, but I'm using timestamp.

The problem occur only in my Messages.tsx component.

This is how I save the timestamp in the DB:
method 1(When I send message to facebook messanger):

```
const timestamp = Date.now();
    const messageData: Message = {
      id: nanoid(),
      senderId: body.teamId,
      text: body.message.text,
      timestamp,
      source: "facebook",
    };
```

method 2: When I receive message from Facebook messanger (using their timestamp):

```
          const messageData: Message = {
            id: webhook_event.message.mid,
            senderId: sender_psid,
            text: webhook_event.message.text,
            timestamp,
            source: "facebook",
          };
```

This is how I format it:

```
  const formatTimestamp = (timestamp: number) => {
    return format(timestamp, "HH:mm");
  };
```

photos of my errors:

[image]
Appreciate you help!

Comment: Usually, how I debug hydration errors is by Disable all JavaScript, then download the full HTML of `body`. After that, enable JavaScript and let client-side rendering kicks in. Copy the full HTML of `body` again and compare using `diff`. Sometimes it might not necessary be issue on your formatting, but rather the state of initial mount / rendering is mismatched.

Comment: I think it has to be something about the formats, 
when I clear the DB (messages table) I get none, then when I send a message from me to Facebook page still no hydration error,
the problem is when I get the message from Facebook.

Comment: What should i look for in the debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably indeed because of different timezones, e.g. yours and Vercel.

> but I'm using timestamp

It does not matter in that case, because you are formatting it to a date anyway. The same timestamp formatted to local date can display different date.

You could use `suppressHydrationWarning`  prop ([docs](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/client/hydrateRoot#suppressing-unavoidable-hydration-mismatch-errors)) for example, on the component which renders you date.

Or you could just not render that component at all on the server. Or force UTC formatting. But `suppressHydrationWarning` is probably the best solution here.

Comment: Yep that did the work, took a look at the docs.
Thank you!